# Why does the list 'magicians' empty at last

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def show_magicians():
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)
magicians=['A','B','C']
show_magicians()
def make_great(old_list):
    new_list=[]
    while old_list:
        new_name='The Great '+old_list.pop()
        new_list.append(new_name)
    old_list=new_list
make_great(magicians)
show_magicians()
```

Comment: `old_list = new_list` assigns a new value to the variable `old_list` (you are breaking its relation to the global variable `magicians`. One way to avoid it would be mutating that variable instead of assigning something new to it (e.g. `old_list.extend(new_list)`.

Comment: You may want to add `return new_list` at the end of the `make_great` funciton`, e.g. after `old_list=new_list`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when you pass `magicians` to the function `make_great`, you aren't making a copy, you are only giving a link like a pointer to it. Hence when you do `old_list.pop` you are actually removing elements from old_list --> which is linked to `magicians`, hence at the end `magicians` is empty. In case you want to copy `magicians` to `old_list` you can use `old_list = magicians[:]`

```
def show_magicians():
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)
magicians=['A','B','C']
show_magicians()
def make_great(old_list):
    new_list=[]
    while old_list:
        new_name='The Great '+old_list.pop()
        new_list.append(new_name)
    old_list=new_list
make_great(magicians[:])
show_magicians()
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in python are "references to objects" (not entirely accurate, but enough for this discussion).

In the line `magicians=['A','B','C']` you do 2 things, create a new list, and also create a global variable named `magicians` that references it.

When you call `make_great(magicians)` you say "call make_great, and have the param `old_list` reference the same list as `magicians`"

Then in the line `new_list=[]` you again do 2 things, create a new empty list, and a var that holds a ref to it.

In the line `old_list=new_list` you say "remember old_list? now make it reference the new_list instead of what it referenced before.

The original `magicians` still references that same list as it did before, which you `pop`ed all elements out of (so is now empty).

You can use the function `id` to get a unique identifier of your actual object (in CPython it's the address in memory where it sits), and see for yourself:

```py
def show_magicians():
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)
magicians=['A','B','C']
print("original magicians:", id(magicians))
show_magicians()
def make_great(old_list):
    print("original old_list:", id(old_list))
    new_list=[]
    print("original new_list:", id(new_list))
    while old_list:
        new_name='The Great '+old_list.pop()
        new_list.append(new_name)
    old_list=new_list
    print("after assign old_list:", id(old_list))
make_great(magicians)
print("final magicians:", id(magicians))
show_magicians()
```

Output:

```
original magicians: 139938559313472 # this is your [A,B,C]
A
B
C
original old_list: 139938559313472 # same as id before
original new_list: 139938558381376 # entirely new id
after assign old_list: 139938558381376 # now old_list also points at this new id
final magicians: 139938559313472 # magicians has the same id as it originally had
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned it up in an attempt understand what is going on more clearly.

```
magicians=['A','B','C']

def show_magicians():
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)
        
def make_great(old_list):
    new_list=[]
    print(old_list is magicians)
    while old_list:
        new_name='The Great '+ old_list.pop()
        new_list.append(new_name)
    old_list = new_list         

show_magicians()
print(f'magicians={magicians}')
make_great(magicians)
print(f'magicians={magicians}')
show_magicians()
```

`magicians` is in the global/module scope.

In the first `show_magicians()` call it's full.

In `make_great()` you create a reference to the *global/module scope* `magicians` called `old_list` and remove the items from the list.

Then in `make_great()` you create a *function scoped* `new_list` and then remap `old_list` so that it no longer references `magicians` and now references `new_list`.

So when you call `show_magicians()` again, you are left with an empty list.

Here's the output of the above cleaned up function:

> A
>
> B
>
> C
>
> magicians=['A', 'B', 'C']
>
> True
>
> magicians=[]